# QWaitCondition returns immediately on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, qt

I want to develop an application in QtCreator using Qt 5.4.
I'm trying to synchronize a communication with a QMutex and a QWaitCondition. The communication runs in a separate thread that requests data and then waits for the answer using QWaitCondition, if the host is not available, the wait conditions returns after the time specified in timeout_ms.

```
mtWait.lock();
bool ret = wcWait.wait(&mtWait, timeout_ms);
mtWait.unlock();
```

The application works well when I run it on my PC (compiled with minGW), but when I use the Build-kit for android (compiler is gcc 4.9), the wait condition returns immediately with a timeout (ret == false).
Only if there is no timeout specified (i.e. the wait condition waits forever), it works as expected. (But the timeout is needed, as the connection may break during runtime.)

Does anybody know this problem or has even a solution for this?

Thank you in advance and best wishes,

Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but maybe this is related
[QTBUG-46047](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46047)
?

If so you have to wait for Qt 5.4.2 or build Qt with patch (see QTBUG-44386)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems to be exactly the problem I have.
Meanwhile I could test the code on a device with android 4.2.x where it works and on other devices with android 5.x versions where the problem occurs on all devices.

Comment: Btw Qt 5.4.2 released